# Help with simplifying very complicated expressions

Tags: simplifying-expressions

The following forms the matrix b:

```
A := Simplify[D[(Sqrt[2]*k*Pi^2*x^2*(x + y + z)*(x + y + z + j + m))/((x + y)*(x + y + z + j)*Sqrt[x + y + z + j + m + n]), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

B := Simplify[D[(Sqrt[2]*k*Pi^2*(x + y + z)*z^2*(y + z + j)*(x + y + z + j + m)*(z + j + m)*Sqrt[y + z + j + m + n])/((y + z)*(x + y + z + j)*(z + j)*(y + z + j + m)*Sqrt[(x + y + z + j + m + n)*(z + j + m + n)]), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

F := Simplify[D[(Sqrt[2]*k*Pi^2*(x + y + z + j + m)*(z + j + m)*m^2*Sqrt[((y + z + j + m + n)*(j + m + n))/((x + y + z + j + m + n)*(z + j + m + n)*(m + n))])/((y + z + j + m)*(j + m)), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

G := Simplify[D[-((2*(-1 + k)*Pi)/k)/(8*Pi), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

H := Simplify[D[-(2*Pi*(1 - ((x + y)*(y + z)*(x + y + z + j)*(y + z + j + m)*Sqrt[(x + y + z + j + m + n)/(y + z + j + m + n)])/(k*y*(x + y + z)*(y + z + j)*(x + y + z + j + m))))/(8*Pi), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

J := Simplify[D[-(2*Pi*(1 - ((x + y + z + j)*(z + j)*(y + z + j + m)*(j + m)*Sqrt[((x + y + z + j + m + n)*(z + j + m + n))/((y + z + j + m + n)*(j + m + n))])/(k*(y + z + j)*j*(x + y + z + j + m)*(z + j + m))))/(8*Pi), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

K := Simplify[D[-(2*Pi - (2*Pi*Sqrt[(x + y + z + j + m + n)*(z + j + m + n)*(m + n)])/(k*Sqrt[(y + z + j + m + n)*(j + m + n)*n]))/(8*Pi), {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]]

b := {A, B, F, G, H, J, K}
```

Now, I need the 2nd, 4th and 6th elements of the first column of the inverted matrix. Instead of manually finding each component, I opted to use:

```
f := LinearSolve[b, {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}]
```

Next, I used:

```
f[[2]] + f[[4]] + f[[6]]
```

to extract the required elements.

Here comes the part I have problems with. In my attempt to simplify the result of the actual sum I want, I used:

```
$Assumptions = Element[k, PositiveReals] && z1 <= z2 <= z3 <= z4 <= z5 <= z6 <= z7 && Element[z1, Reals] && Element[z2, Reals] && Element[z3, Reals] && Element[z4, Reals] && Element[z5, Reals] && Element[z6, Reals] && Element[z7, Reals]
TimeConstrained[Simplify[Together[((3*Pi)/4)*(f[[2]] + f[[4]] + f[[6]]) //. {x -> z2 - z1, y -> z3 - z2, z -> z4 - z3, j -> z5 - z4, m -> z6 - z5, n -> z7 - z6}]], 3600]
```

Even with an hour, Mathematica couldn't simplify the result.

The result I want is:

```
((-z1 + z3)*(-z1 + z5)*Sqrt[-z1 + z7])/(2*Pi*Sqrt[2]*k*(-z1 + z2)*(-z1 + z4)*(-z1 + z6))
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Replace := by = in the matrix definition,  then use Inverse.

Comment: There seems to be some regularity in your equations.  You should make it explicit.  Maybe express then as a function of dimension, that is 7 in your case.  Thus, you may able to examine smaller dimensions first, and see what problems arise.

Comment: `K` is a reserved symbol. Better do not assign to it.

Comment: Use `D[..., {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}, 1}]` instead of `D[..., {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]` when taking derivatives with respect to a symbolic vector.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher  `D[f, {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}, 1}] == D[f, {{k, x, y, z, j, m, n}}]`

Comment: @cvgmt Oops, I see. It is the additional pair of braces that does it. =)